# How to improve the "happiness set point"?

Tags: happiness

In Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedonic_treadmill) it says: "The hedonic treadmill, also known as hedonic adaptation, is the observed tendency of humans to quickly return to a relatively stable level of happiness despite major positive or negative events or life changes." This stable level is referred to as the happiness set point.

Are there strategies (backed up by studies / research) that improve this stable level?